# How to import a google svn into eclipse/subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am trying to import that svn into subclipse:
http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/checkout

But I get that error:

> mkdir --parents -m "Initial import."
>   http://cloud-tasks-io.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/test
>       svn: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/!svn/act/71937bda-3601-0010-a1a3-7d548ee24bfd': 405 Method Not
>   Allowed (http://cloud-tasks-io.googlecode.com) svn: MKACTIVITY request
>   failed on '/svn/!svn/act/71937bda-3601-0010-a1a3-7d548ee24bfd'
>       svn: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/!svn/act/71937bda-3601-0010-a1a3-7d548ee24bfd': 405 Method Not
>   Allowed (http://cloud-tasks-io.googlecode.com) svn: MKACTIVITY request
>   failed on '/svn/!svn/act/71937bda-3601-0010-a1a3-7d548ee24bfd'

Why cannot I import that svn into subclipse?

greetings and thx in advance

Comment: What is the exact SVN command you are issuing to do the import?

Comment: I put that in eclipse: http://cloud-tasks-io.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/test

Comment: This is a permissions problem (usually only) occurs when you try to _commit_ without enough permissions. Simple checkout should work fine. Did you try simply checking out the code using SVN and then importing it into Eclipse?

Comment: Excuse me, but what does this have to do with AppEngine?

Comment: kk thx for your replys!!! 1. I want to load that project into my ide 2. In fact its the c2dm project they coded at google IO 2011 and I want to test it...(that is why I mentioned app engine)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing a lot of things wrong.

1. It seems like you are trying to add something that you have in Eclipse to that Google repository?  But your question sounds like your goal was to checkout.
2. You are not using the right URL.  You should open the SVN perspective and then add a repository with this URL: http://cloud-tasks-io.googlecode.com/svn/
3. You should then be able to expand that repository to the folder that contains the project you want to checkout.

Note that as stated on the page you linked to, this repository URL is Read-Only.  So if you really do want to commit new code to this project you have to be a member of the project with proper permissions AND you have to use the URL that allows write access.  Google provides that URL somewhere, but I seem to recall it it just the same URL except you use https:// instead of http://